# Advice on creating PHP-MySQL background tasks

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm looking for advice on something I'm building: I have a PHP app that creates, updates and deletes records, but it's tightly integrated in a legacy non-sql based database, and it gets to be really really slow when you start doing lots of DB calls.
I want to make this more of a background experience for the user, so that when user creates or edits something, all the variables, arrays and objects would need to be written to a MySQL database and then a background script would kick off to read those records and process the request to the legacy database.

So I would need one table that keeps track of the task and then another table that would track all of the variables, objects, arrays and their values.

Here's what I was thinking the DB structure of the 2nd table would have to be:

- A column to store the task_id
- A column to store if the var is an array or an object, or NULL if it's a simple var.
- A column to store the name of the array/object var.
- A column for if it's an object, then to store the type of object it is.
- A column to store the array/object group ID. (For keeping track of what vars belongs to the object/array)
- A column to store the name of a simple var, method or name in the object/array
- A column to store the value of the var

Here would be a few examples:

```
1 | NULL     | NULL        | NULL          | NULL | 'foo'        | 'bar'
1 | 'array'  | 'foo_array' | NULL          | 1    | 'foo'        | 'bar'
1 | 'array'  | 'foo_array' | NULL          | 1    | 'foo2'       | 'bar2'
1 | 'object' | 'foo_obj'   | foobar_object | 2    | 'foo_method' | 'bar'
1 | 'object' | 'foo_obj'   | foobar_object | 2    | 'bar_method' | 'foo'
```

Does this seem like an overly complicated approach? Am I crazy and over thinking this? Can someone think of a better way I should approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: It almost sounds like this approach could make the experience worse, as user interactions won't be written to your database until the queue is processed. Any reason you can't migrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize)()

It will generate a specially formatted string(you can store in your database). The string is special in that [unserialize](http://www.php.net/unserialize)() can translate it back into its original php value. It maintains a variables type, value, and structure. Custom objects, and multidimensional arrays are no problem.

You still need part of your db table, this just does a lot of the work for you, and does it very well.

Comment: You just blew my mind chris! Thank you, clearly this will be a lot easier than I expected!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table that has a primary key (task_id perhaps) and then a column to store a serialized hash of variables (or maybe json encoded). You could even store this in the original table that keeps track of the task. I'm assuming that table would have a status column with values for:

waiting,
processing,
complete, and
error

When we do this in house we just use a tinyint(1) unsigned column. You could also add a timestamp field or three for when the task was create, started, and finished. It's all pretty straight-forward once you get rolling.

Comment: Yea exactly, ID of the status and a few other things to identify the line. And yea, you're right, I probably only need 1 table for all of this data. Why do you store the serialized hash of the variables? Why not just store it as is? Just for security sakes?

Comment: I normally store it as a hash so that it is more easily parsed and I can store an indefinite amount of data. Some tasks might need 2 variables, others might need 50. By using a hash I am able to store all the info in a single column.